# Reducing queries Yii2

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, yii2

I`m really stuck on this one.

I have a table with contracts, and one with items.
What I`m trying to achieve is to see the total quantity of an item on contracts in a date range for every day.
For example, item1 appears on 3 contracts on Monday and the total quantity is 30.
Currently, I`m doing a while loop for each day in the selected date range and using this query

```
$itemQty = ContItems::find()
            ->where(['ITEMNO' => $itemNo])
            ->andWhere(['<=' , 'HIREDATE' , $today])
            ->andWhere(['>=' , 'ESTRETD' , $today])
            ->andWhere(['or',
                ['STATUS' => 0],
                ['STATUS' => 1]
            ])
            ->SUM('QTY');
```

It is working fine, but I want to check for every item I have for each day in the selected date range, and the number of queries goes up to 50k+ if I do that.

What I tried to do is selected every contract in a date range and stored in an array
Every contract has a start and end date and I want to select every contract where the start or end date is in the date range I specified.

```
$ContItemsArray = ContItems::find()
            ->where(['or',
                        ['<=' , 'HIREDATE' , $dateFrom],
                        ['<=' , 'HIREDATE' , $dateTo],
                        ['>=' , 'HIREDATE' , $dateFrom],
                        ['>=' , 'ESTRETD' , $dateTo],
                        ['>=' , 'ESTRETD' , $dateFrom]
                    ])
            ->andWhere(['or',
                ['STATUS' => 0],
                ['STATUS' => 1]
            ])
            ->asArray()
            ->all();
```

And use this code to count the quantities

```
$theQty = 0;    
        foreach ($ContItemsArray as $subArray) 
        {   
            if ($subArray['ITEMNO'] == $itemNo && ($subArray['HIREDATE'] <= $today && $subArray['ESTRETD'] >= $today) && ($subArray['STATUS'] <= 1))
            {   
                $theQty += $subArray['QTY'];
            }
            else 
            {
                $theQty += 0;
            }       
        }
```

But it is returning incorrect numbers, contracts are missing for some reason and I can`t figure it out why.
I tried to change around the query for the $ContItemsArray but with no luck.
I hope I was clear enough with the question.
I would appreciate any help.

Edit:
ContItems table has all the contracts with the item number 'ITEMNO' start date 'HIREDATE' end date 'ESTRETD' and the quantity 'QTY' fields.

And I have an array with all the item numbers what I want to check.
The expected result would be, if the day I`m checking is between the contract start date and end date, sum the qty of the items.

Comment: Still unclear to me. Can you please provide sample data and expected output also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, had to use date('Y-m-d') and strtotime on the dates coming from the table (HIREDATE, ESTRETD) and now it is working fine